# protractor, AssertionError: expected '24' to be a number or a date

Tags: javascript, protractor, assert

i need to check that there are more than twelve elements listed in a page.
I did it, but on expectation I have this error:

```
AssertionError: expected '24' to be a number or a date
```

Now, 24 is obviously a number, so what is the problem?? Why this assertion error?
Can you help me to solve this?

Here my stepdefinition.js

```
Given('there are more than twelve elements listed', function (next) {
    let listed_count = element(by.css('span[class="total-results"]'));
    listed_count.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log('How much elements?: ', text);
            browser.sleep(1111);
            return expect(text).to.be.above(12);
      })
      next();
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

listed_count.getText() returns text. You need to convert it into number:

```
parseInt(text);
```